# AWS Elastic Beanstalk Deployment Order

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, ebcli

I'm deploying code to a single-instance web server AWS EB environment that will provision/update my connected RDS database.  I've got an .ebextensions file that calls deployment code:

```
---
container_commands:
  01deploydb:
    command: /var/www/html/php/cli/deploy-db.php
    leader_only: true
```

On the same deployment, I dropped the deploy-db.php file back one directory into `/cli/`.  On deployment, I get `ERROR: [Instance: i-*****] Command failed on instance. Return code: 127 Output: /bin/sh: /var/www/html/php/cli/deploy-db.php: No such file or directory. 
container_command 01deploydb in .ebextensions/01_db.config failed. For more detail, check /var/log/eb-activity.log using console or EB CLI.`

If I deploy a version that does not include the command, then deploy a second update including the command, there is no error.  However, adding the command and the file it calls at the same time produces the error.  A similar sequence occurred earlier with a different command/file.

**My question is: is there a documented order/sequence for how AWS updates the environment?**  I would have expected that my new version would have fully deployed (and the .php file installed) before container_commands are called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The commands: section runs before the project files are put in place. This is where you can install server packages for example.

The container_commands: section runs in a staging directory before the files are put in its final destination. Here you can modify your files if you need to. Current path is this staging directory so you can run it like this (I might get the app directory wrong, maybe it should be `php/cli/deploy-db.php`)

```
container_commands:
  01deploydb:
    command: cli/deploy-db.php
    leader_only: true
```

Reference for above: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html

You can also run a post deploy scripts. This is not very well documented (at least it wasn't). You can do something like this (it won't be leader only though, but you could put a file in this directory through a `container_commands:`):

```
files:
    "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post/99_deploy.sh":
        mode: "000755"
        owner: root
        group: root
        content: |
            #!/usr/bin/env bash
            /var/www/html/php/cli/deploy-db.php
```